# Meteor and Iron Router Create and Use anchor/hash inter-page tags

Tags: html, meteor, iron-router

I've read a large number of posts, docs, and SO questions about this and am still too confused to apply any solution.

My use case is that I'd like to leave a URL, say on SO. That URL would be http://my-site.com/page1/#anchor or http://my-site.com/page1#anchor. It would take people to the place marked "anchor" of http://my-site.com/page1 .

I understand that an anchor may not exist until the page gets rendered in full by the client JS so the usual HTML5 encoding does not work by itself in the meteor template. I'm using Iron Router and the latest Meteor and the page is rendered on the client and reactive. I'd like to use this quite a bit so am looking for something doesn't require a change to router.js for each anchor but anything that works is appreciated.

What should I do to make an anchor work generically?

Thanks for unconfusing me.

Comment: If I not now wrong you want a url like  http://my-site.com/page1/#anchor from anchor tag or Router.go ? Can you please conform ?

Comment: The URL will be from the outside world--a standard HTML5 URL, maybe typed into the URL bar. What I need is template and/or router code to react to receiving the URL and go to the bookmark/anchor/page location indicated in the URL. Don't know if that means Router.go or something else.